# Passing query string data to form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.5

I am trying to use some data given by query string in my form. I have searched the internet and found a good explaination (http://bicknoyle.com/2014/04/passing-query-string-params-form-symfony/):

```
class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('refer', 'user_refer_type');

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
            if (isset($options['request'])) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $form->get('source')->setData($options['request']->query->get('source'));
            }
        });
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setOptional(array(
            'request'
        ));

        $resolver->setAllowedTypes(array(
            'request' => 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request'
        ));
    }
```

I found another way using the request scope:

```
class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{

    private $request = null;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('refer', 'user_refer_type');

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event)
        {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $form->get('refer')->setData($this->request->query->get('refer'));
        });
    }
```

I have some questions about the code:

1. What is the "better" way to implement such thing?
   In general I can summarize, the first approach needs access to the controller to pass the request object and the second needs request scope.
2. Did I miss another good way?

Comment: I think that the second way it's "better", because you don't have to use `setOptional` and `setAllowedTypes` so less code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use the second approach, but instead of injecting the Request object you should inject RequestStack service according to [this post](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack)..

Here is some eaxmple how I usually do it:

```
class CustomType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var RequestStack
     */
    private $requestStack;

    /**
     * @param RequestStack $requestStack
     */
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $currentRequest = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

        ...

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($currentRequest)
        {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $form->get('refer')->setData($currentRequest->query->get('refer'));
        });
    }

    ...
}
```